# "Monsta" as "Monster" abbreviation?

Tags: american-english, british-english, slang, abbreviations

Can "Monsta" be a correct slang word or abbreviation for "Monster"?

Sounds good and cute to me but as a non-native speaker I don't understand if it's actually a word that natives may use (maybe kids?).

Comment: I don't think it much of an abbreviation....more an alternative .

Comment: 'Correct' and 'slang' make strange bedfellows.

Comment: Also, "natives" often means something different from "native English speakers".

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it appears that *monsta* is used (albeit very rarely) in place of *monster*, similar to how *gangsta* is used instead of *gangster*.

According to the [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/248833?redirectedFrom=gangsta) (← free page!), the spelling of *gangsta* is "intended to reflect an African-American pronunciation", and that's what I've seen for most of the examples I've found for *monsta* as well.

---

Some examples:

- [You Created A Monsta](http://lyrics.wikia.com/wiki/K-Rino:You_Created_A_Monsta) (song)
- [I NEEDUH MONSTA TA CLOBBA DAT DAIR KIRBEH](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m5UEG0eS1vs) (Youtube video)
- > I've created a monsta, 'cause nobody wantsta see Marshall no more, they want Shady I'm chopped liva (Rap on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Eminem/comments/7fqgm6/ive_created_a_monsta_cause_nobody_wantsta_see/))
- > I'm only the humanshaped pokemonsta, fam chill. ([Deersa Trap!](https://aminoapps.com/c/pokemon/page/user/deersa-traps/o6hJ_fd0d2824LXVlMPm1MP8gRpzv)'s bio on Pokémon Amino)

Answer (score 0):

Using "monsta" would be fine, in a slang sort of way. However, if you are writing anything more formal, monster is the correct term.